# Enviar JSON de Servlet a AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, json, servlets

tengo este código, pero no me ha sido posible enviar los datos JSON desde el servlet a AJAX, el código que he construido es el siguiente:

Lo ideal es que los datos que agrupe el JSON se traigan de la una BD de MySQL, pero como apenas estoy resolviendo el AJAX, estoy creando un JSON básico, sin embargo, no me está trayendo la informacion.

Código JSP y AJAX

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demo AJAX</title>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bttHola').click(function(){
        var namex=$('#name').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                name:namex
            },
            datatype:"json", 
            url:'AjaxController',
            success: function(result){
                
                alert(result);
                
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form >
    Name<input type="text" id="name">
    
    <input type="button" value="Hola" id="bttHola" onclick="">
    <br>
    <span id="result1"></span>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Código del Servlet

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AjaxController
 */
@WebServlet("/AjaxController")
public class AjaxController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AjaxController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        
        JSONObject json= new  JSONObject();
        
        
        
        json.put("cedula", "12345");
        json.put("nombre", name);
        
                
            
        out.print(json);
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Tengo habilitadas las librerias de JSON Simple

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola Amigos, tengo este código, pero no me ha sido posible enviar los datos JSON desde el servlet a AJAX, el código que he construido es el siguiente:

Lo ideal es que los datos que agrupe el JSON se traigan de la una BD de MySQL, pero como apenas estoy resolviendo el AJAX, estoy creando un JSON básico, sin embargo, no me está trayendo la informacion.

Comment: segun lo que veo ahora es que estas intentando mostrar un atributo de texto `String name=request.getParameter("name");` cuendo en realidad enviaste un objeto json llamado data `String data=request.getParameter("data");` y luego haces el parseo de data a JSON. no lo he probado, intenta y si no avisame. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Encontré esta solución:

1 Agregar librería gson,
2 Crear una clase para instanciar el objeto que enviaré al Ajax desde el Servlet,
3 Crear Servlet y
4 agregar la librería Jquery

Estructurar de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código Ajax

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demo AJAX</title>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bttHola').click(function(){
        var namex=$('#name').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                name:namex
            },
            datatype:"json", 
            url:'AjaxController',
            success: function(result){
                
                alert(result.nombre);
                alert(result.cedula);
                
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form >
    Name<input type="text" id="name">
    
    <input type="button" value="Hola" id="bttHola" onclick="">
    <br>
    <span id="result1"></span>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Código Servlet

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class AjaxController
 */
@WebServlet("/AjaxController")
public class AjaxController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AjaxController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            
    }
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        
        
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        
        Ajax obj_Ajax=new Ajax(name,"1234");
        String employeeJsonString = this.gson.toJson(obj_Ajax);

        
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out.print(employeeJsonString);
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Código de la Clase

```
package controller;

public class Ajax {
    
    private String nombre;
    private String cedula;
    
    public Ajax(String nombre, String cedula) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }
    
    

}
```